# i cant view all data when i using Datepicker on 'WHERE'

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

hy, please help me,, i cant view all data from emp0003 to checking all employee absence..

emp0003 table

| NIK | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 01190301 | Susan |
| 01190302 | Jamed |

dvc0004 table's

| NIK | Enroll |
| --- | --- |
| 01190301 | 2021-02-03 08:06:27 |
| 01190302 | 2021-02-02 18:52:15 |
| 01190302 | 2021-02-02 08:02:32 |
| 01190302 | 2021-02-01 20:07:13 |
| 01190301 | 2021-02-01 20:07:13 |
| 01190302 | 2021-02-01 07:55:49 |
| 01190301 | 2021-02-01 07:55:49 |

this is my code :

```
SELECT
            emp0003.NIK,
            emp0003.`Name`,
            IF(emp0003.NIK=dvc0004.NIK,'Attended','Not Attended') as Attendance
            FROM
            emp0003
            left JOIN
            dvc0004
            ON
            emp0003.NIK = dvc0004.NIK
            WHERE
            DATE(dvc0004.Enroll) = '2021-02-02'
```

and the result my code :

| NIK | Name | Attendance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01190302 | Jamed | Attended |

The result should be :

| NIK | Name | Attendance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01190302 | Susan | Not Attended |
| 01190302 | Jamed | Attended |

please help me

Comment: Try changing `WHERE DATE(dvc0004.Enroll) = '2021-02-02'` to `AND DATE(dvc0004.Enroll) = '2021-02-02'` and see what happens

Comment: Please edit your RDBMS tags. Although MySQL and MariaDB is quite similar, there are still differences between them and sql-server is totally different.

Comment: @FaNo_FN : thank for helping, i try the code and nothing happen

Comment: @FaNo_FN : okey, thanks im edited the tags

Comment: Are you sure the query return only one row? I've tested it return two duplicate rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the date condition on `dvc0004` into the `JOIN` condition, otherwise it converts the join to an inner join, which is why you get no results for `Susan`. Also, you need to use either `SELECT DISTINCT` or a `GROUP BY` clause to remove duplicate rows (since in your sample data `Jamed` enrolled twice on `2021-02-02`). I've gone with `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       emp0003.NIK,
       emp0003.`Name`,
       CASE WHEN dvc0004.NIK IS NULL THEN 'Not Attended' ELSE 'Attended' END as Attendance
FROM emp0003
LEFT JOIN dvc0004 ON emp0003.NIK = dvc0004.NIK AND DATE(dvc0004.Enroll) = '2021-02-02'
```

Output:

```
NIK         Name    Attendance
1190302     Jamed   Attended
1190301     Susan   Not Attended
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=25dcc3dae85aabe21e6b0db33c8359a2)

Comment: @eja_noob . . . Using a `LEFT JOIN` with `SELECT DISTINCT` may work, but this is way less performant than alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly, strongly recommend that you use `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT e.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM dvc0004 d
                          WHERE e.NIK = d.NIK AND
                                d.Enroll >= '2021-02-02' AND
                                d.Enroll < '2021-02-03'
                         ) 
             THEN 'Attended' ELSE 'Not Attended'
        END) as Attendance
FROM emp0003 e;
```

With an index on `dvc0004(NIK, Enroll)` this should be quite fast.

Note that this solution handles multiple enrollments on the same day *without* using `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`.  That is a big win for performance.